# Resources to learn about particles on a grid/mesh

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, crystals, lattice-model

I am looking to learn about averaging out a particle gas or any other type of organization of particles within a system or volume that can be approximated onto a grid or mesh where the particles are at a constant distance from each other: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_mesh.

Basically, what I am looking for is a method of converting a moving system of particles onto a lattice or grid by averaging the motion. This is a kind of approximation.

I am not sure where to find this kind of material. The closest I have found are these:

- FPGA-Accelerated Particle-Grid Mapping: https://www.bu.edu/caadlab/FCCM16b.pdf
- Some book from 1988: [Computer Simulation Using Particles | R W Hockney, J W Eastwood | Tayl](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9780367806934/computer-simulation-using-particles-hockney-eastwood) but I would like something much more modern than this

Any recommendations would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: The word you're looking for is [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_model_(physics)).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yes, I think that also fits my description. Do you know of any models or techniques that convert a system of particles (such as a gas) into a lattice (averaging) and where to learn about this kind of method?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Basically, what I am looking for is the averaging of a moving system of particles into a lattice with spacing between them constant or changing.

Comment: The point of my comment is that most physicists don't use the term "grid" or "mesh", but instead "lattice", and that's why you have trouble finding resources. Searching for lattice models/lattice theory should give you much better results. However, I'm afraid I do not understand at all how a *gas* should be usefully approximated by a lattice - there's a reason we usually use lattice models for *solid* bodies - an object where the particles sit approximately in a fixed lattice is a solid pretty much by definition!

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you for your comment. I think I understand now. I will try searching for lattice theory and the like.